# How to open full screen popup in IE7&IE8 from javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to open popup in full screen from javascript in IE7 & IE8. Basically I am using

window.open('default.aspx','OnlineTest','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes');

this not working. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

The browser blocks popups by default. You can not get around this. The user has to allow the domain to open popups.

You can use modals/pop-unders instead, using iframes and such.